# Can I have multiple web api dlls in the same site?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a need to provide a variety of Web APIs on a single site/url. My intent is to have API #1 in a project with API #2 in a separate project so that if I make changes to API #2 I can deploy without messing with API #1. I've done some tests and this seems to work but what happens if there are conflicting routes in each project?

Is there another way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: how are you going to deploy this in IIS?

Comment: Was thinking just one site with both DLLs. Although I've since decided to put the separate DLLs/APIs into subsites off of the main site.

Comment: you're going to need something to 'listen' for the requests coming in. You could have one main 'app' that depends on other projects, containing your controllers etc...

Comment: Regarding conflicts, I would recommend just registering your APIs under different roots so  /api/firstservice/somemethod and /api/otherservice/nextmethod.

On the other topic, you can use something like autofac or MEF to scan folders for changes in assemblies